# Error installing Yeoman on Yosemite

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman

I'm trying by several days to install the Yeoman in my OS X but I can't =/

When I try to install I get this error:

```
Mac-Pro:~ pauloricardo$ sudo npm i -g yo
Password:

> spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/cross-spawn/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

sh: node: command not found
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall script 'node postinstall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the spawn-sync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node postinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spawn-sync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/pauloricardo/npm-debug.log
```

I already tried to install as a root user and cleaning the npm cache. But I get the same.

If anyone wants see my npm log, here's the link: http://pastebin.com/Arb6i58q

I'll be very grateful for any help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm yo`. This is some sort of permission issue. Take a look at this github thread, they offer a few other solutions as well https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/spawn-sync/issues/11.

Comment: Looks like this will help you a lot @user3130064

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have node installed on your machine.

https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5.pkg

After installing that:

```
npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp
```

Comment: Or he hasn't in the common `$PATH`

Comment: If npm runs that means he has node installed.

Comment: The problem is here `Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.11 postinstall script 'node postinstall'.`

Comment: I Have the node installed, and others modules such as grunt, gulp, bower working fine. It just happen when I try to install the yeoman